# Html and CSS - text not in the same height

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to put an svg and two texts in one line. The second text should align right.

However, if I set the second text `float:right`, these two texts would not be in the same height.

Here is my jsbin
https://jsbin.com/gupunu/edit?html,output

This is the result.
[image: Result]

I have tried `text-align`, `padding`, `margin`. Nothing affects the first text.
I would like to put current first text to the same height as the second text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `vertical-align: top` to the first `span`:

```
<div width='50px'>
  <svg width='20px' height='20px'>
     <rect x=0 y=0 width='20px' height='20px' fill='blue'>
  <span class='1' style="vertical-align: top;">Hello</span>
  <span class='2' style="float:right;">World</span>
</div>
<div width='50px'>
  <svg width='20px' height='20px'>
     <rect x=0 y=0 width='20px' height='20px' fill='blue'>
  <span class='1' style="vertical-align: top;">Hello</span>
  <span class='2' style="float:right;">World</span>
</div>
```